# Datawarehouse duplicate dimension rows

Tags: sql, duplicates, data-warehouse, bulkinsert, vertica

We're starting to load up a datawarehouse with data from event logs.  We have a normal star schema where a row in the fact table represents one event.  Our dimension tables are a typical combination of user_agent, ip, referal, page, etc.  One dimension table looks like this:

```
create table referal_dim(
  id integer,
  domain varchar(255),
  subdomain varchar(255),
  page_name varchar(4096),
  query_string varchar(4096)
  path varchar(4096)
)
```

Where we autogenerate the id to eventually join against the fact table.  My question is: whats the best way to identify duplicate records in our bulk load process?  We upload all the records for a log file into temp tables before doing the actual insert into the persistent store, however, the id is just auto-incremented, so two identical dim records from two days would have different ids.  Would creating a hash of the value columns be appropriate and then trying to compare on that?  It seems like trying to compare on each value column would be slow.  Is there any best practices for a situation like this?

Comment: What platform are you using, sql server? Oracle? MySql? Version?

Comment: He is using Vertica, but I believe he is asking how to normalize incoming data into his dimension table while keeping a reference in the fact tables.  If he does a lookup on every row to find out if a dimension already exists for a given fact then when you get into the millions of rows it will get very slow.  Hashing the columns to create a primary key may be a viable solution but you have to then worry about the birthday paradox and possible collisions.

Comment: you can use unique key , if duplicate entries can be inserted by id(if it's auto increment)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Auto-increment integer for a surrogate PK is OK, but (according to Mr. Kimball) a dimension table should also have a natural key too. So a hash `NaturalKey` column would be in order, also a `Status` column for "current" or "expired" may be useful to allow for SCD type 2.

Comment: Cool, a hashed naturalkey is what we were thinking about to go along with our surrogate id, but we weren't sure what the performance tradeoff would be.

Comment: To improve loading performance, you can maintain (re-create after each load) a key matching table for the dimension like (NaturalKey, PrKey) which matches natural keys with the latest primary key for the table. During loading, add a hash column to you records, than look-up the primary key from the KeyMatchingTable. If not found, means it is a new record so stage those for inserts. If found, means it already exists, so decide what to do (discard, SC1 or SC2). Then load the dimension table.